# Convert Date in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string with day and month name. How can I convert to standard date?
**I have this :**

```
Tue 19Jul16 13:30
```

**I want to show me this :**

```
2016/07/19 13:30
```

Comment: `echo date('Y/m/d H:i', strtotime('Tue 19Jul16 13:30')); // 2016/07/19 13:30`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one..

```
$str = "Tue 19Jul16 13:30";

echo date('Y/m/d H:i', strtotime($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert html date this is the code I prepared in javascript just pass $date to cnvrt() from php

```
function cnvrt(datee)
{
var d=datee;
  month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

   datee= [month, day, year].join('/');

}
```

So rather than echo you can use the date wherever you need